# OSGi API version mismatch exception issue

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to port a Java project in OSGi. This project depends on some third-party JARs ([librealsense JavaCPP presets](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets)). I'm using Eclipse for development.

I've tested the configuration using a subset of what I need and failed miserably.
The code I've used for testing is the following:

```
package testinglibrariesplugin;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.RealSense.*;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");

        try {
           context context1 = new context();
           device device = context1.get_device(0);

           String devName = device.get_name().getString();

           System.out.println(devName);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Goodbye World!!");
    }

}
```

Manifest.mf:

```
...
Bundle-ClassPath: src/bundletesting/ffmpeg-linux-x86_64.jar,
 src/bundletesting/ffmpeg-linux-x86.jar,
 src/bundletesting/ffmpeg-platform.jar,
 src/bundletesting/ffmpeg.jar,
 src/bundletesting/javacpp.jar,
 src/bundletesting/javacv.jar,
 src/bundletesting/librealsense-linux-x86_64.jar,
 src/bundletesting/librealsense-linux-x86.jar,
 src/bundletesting/librealsense-platform.jar,
 src/bundletesting/librealsense.jar,
 src/bundletesting/opencv-linux-x86_64.jar,
 src/bundletesting/opencv-linux-x86.jar,
 src/bundletesting/opencv-platform.jar,
 src/bundletesting/opencv.jar,
 .
```

build.properties:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               src/bundletesting/ffmpeg-linux-x86_64.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/ffmpeg-linux-x86.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/ffmpeg-platform.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/ffmpeg.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/javacpp.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/javacv.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/librealsense-linux-x86_64.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/librealsense-linux-x86.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/librealsense-platform.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/librealsense.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/opencv-linux-x86_64.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/opencv-linux-x86.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/opencv-platform.jar,\
               src/bundletesting/opencv.jar
```

The jar files I've used are downloadable [from my Github repo](https://github.com/mattdibi/RSPassengerCounter/tree/master/java_src/jar_files).

I get the following error:

```
Hello World!!
java.lang.RuntimeException: API version mismatch: librealsense.so was compiled with API version 1.12.1 but the application was compiled with 1.9.6! Make sure correct version of the library is installed (make install)
```

Since the code works using only Java I must assume there's a configuration problem in Eclipse/OSGi. I would like to ignore this API mismatch but I'm not really experienced in this environment and I don't know how to proceed. If this is not the correct way to fix the problem please tell me.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This is the code I've used in a plain Java application and that works:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.RealSense.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        context context = new context();
        device device = context.get_device(0);

        String devName = device.get_name().getString();

        System.out.println(devName);

    }

}
```

Output: `Intel RealSense SR300` as expected.

EDIT 2: I added my build.properties and manifest files

Comment: Are you sure this problem is OSGi related? What happens if you run your code from a simple main method in a plain java application?

Comment: I tried and it works flawlessly...

Comment: Did you use the same api dependencies in both cases?

Comment: I used the same JARs in both cases. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. No idea why it should produce different results. Maybe you can put the full code of the example on github so people can actually try it.

Comment: I already posted the full code XD. I'll add some more information in the question about my Manifest file etc...

Comment: Since I'm curious as to how this cpp lib works under Java, I tried to get this code to run in Java but I get a `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniRealSense in java.library.pat` error. How do you get this jni lib so I can try to run this stuff?

Comment: It should be already inside the jar files as they are the interface to the installed library. Have you installed the library? [link to the library](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense) To compile use: javac -cp jar_files/librealsense-platform.jar Main.java and then to run it: java -cp jar_files/librealsense-platform.jar:. Main

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining about this lib:

```
librealsense.so was compiled with API version 1.12.1 but the application was compiled with 1.9.6!
```

It does not seem to be Java, unless they just forgot to remove the `.so` from the name?

Anyway, the error mentions that your app was compiled against the wrong version, so this is not a runtime OSGi error (especially considering you're embedding the jars into your app bundle). It's your class' bytecode that seems to be referring to code from the 1.9.6 version of the library, when the version that is present at runtime is 1.12.1.

It's hard to diagnose (without inspecting each jar you've got) as you don't seem to be using a proper build system (you have jars in your source control!).

I suggest you verify that your compilation step includes the exact same jars as you give to OSGi at runtime, so this problem should go away.

Comment: I am sure I am using the exact same jars. I have recently contacted the mantainers of the JavaCPP project and they told me that they are using the 1.9.6 version of the library to generate those interface jar files. I think this is the problem. On my machine apparently I have the 1.12.1 version of the library installed and this causes the exception. Since the plain java version doesn't break I concluded it must be the OSGi framework that has some more strict rules about version compatibility...